# If $f(1)=3$, $f'(1)=2$, $f''(1)=4$, then $(f^{-1})''(3) =$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function-theorem

I tried using the inverse function theorem, but the answer I got through that was $-1$.

The answer key says the answer is $-1/2$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How did you arrive at the answer? It's difficult to know where you went wrong without knowing the steps you took.

Comment: Also, a MathJax tip: to get multiple characters into a power, use curly braces `{}` to group the characters you want in the power. For example, `$f^-1$` produces $f^-1$, whereas `$f^{-1}$` produces $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

$$
f(g(x))=x\Rightarrow f'(g(x))g'(x)=1\Rightarrow g'(x)={1\over f'(g(x))}
$$

$$
g''(x)=-{f''(g(x))g'(x)\over (f'(g(x)))^2}=-{f''(g(x))\over (f'(g(x)))^3}
$$

Substituting values

$$
g''(3)=-{f''(g(3))\over (f'(g(3)))^3}=-{f''(1)\over (f'(1))^3}=-{4\over8}=-{1\over2}
$$

Comment: You just handed the answer to someone who showed no evidence of even attempting the problem.

Comment: i somehow got f'(g(3)) raised to 2 instead of 3 when i tried it. thank you for the answer!!